# iOS: adjusting position of UINavgationBar title

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I changed the font & size of the UINavigationBar Title, but doing so made the title not align properly anymore so I thought this `"setTitlePositionAdjustment:"` should work but it does not (unrecognized selector). How do I adjust the title´s position?

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)],
  UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cochin-Bold" size:24.0],
  UITextAttributeFont,
  nil]];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, 10)]; // Crash
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call the method setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:forBarMetrics: instead.

For example:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:10.0 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Check the [UINavigationBar class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationBar/setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:forBarMetrics:) for more details on the method.

Comment: Thank you!  Couldn't figure this out for the life of me :)